# Is a recursive definition of type theory primitives in its own terms possible?

Tags: type-theory

In particular, I was thinking of a construction in the vein of this:

$$\mathbb{N} : {\mathcal{U}_0}$$
$$0 : \mathbb{N}$$
$$\lambda n. n' : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$$
$$\lambda n. {\mathcal{U}_n} : \prod_{n : \mathbb{N}} {\mathcal{U}_{n'}}$$
$$\lambda n. \lambda m. \lambda {\tau : {\mathcal{U}_n}}. \lambda {\pi : {\mathcal{U}_m}}. \lambda {f : \tau \rightarrow \pi}. \prod_{x : \tau} {f(x)} : \prod_{n : \mathbb{N}} \prod_{m : \mathbb{N}} \prod_{\alpha : {\mathcal{U}_n}} \prod_{\beta : {\mathcal{U}_m}} (\alpha \rightarrow \beta) \rightarrow \operatorname{?}$$
where $a \rightarrow b = \prod_{\text{_} : a} b$$

Is this alone sufficient to define the use of these operators?

I don't know what would fit in the place of $?$, though.

Answer (score 0):

Agda works this way. However, it has a special built-in type indexing the universes called `Level`, rather than the plain inductively defined naturals. I think this is mainly to allow it to have some fancier constructions/solvers for levels without affecting how the natural numbers behave.

For instance, your $λn. \mathcal U_n$ can be written:

```
Type : (l : Level) → Set (suc l)
Type l = Set l
```

(Agda's universes are named `Set`.) Your last example doesn't make sense, though. $π$ is not a universe, so it doesn't make sense to use $f$ like a type family for forming a $Π$ type. That's probably why you had trouble coming up with something to fill in the question mark.

Agda does one more thing, but I think it isn't necessary depending on how your type theory is presented. Essentially, types are not prior to universes in Agda, but declared as being in a particular universe. So, when you do that, you can then wonder what universe the type `(l : Level) → Set (suc l)` is in. The answer in Agda is `Setω`. If you wonder which universe *that* is in, I think that finally has no answer, unless you enable a flag that says the answer is again `Setω`, but the latter is inconsistent.

If types are considered to stand alone, with universes just classifying subcollections of them, though, I think this step is unnecessary. $\prod_{n:ℕ}{\mathcal U_n}$ could just be a type that doesn't belong to a universe.